# Mysql database copy for offline use

Tags: c#, mysql, database

My application reads data from an mysql database to a datagridview, some users want the ability to have a offline database option.

What is the best way to save the mysql database to a local file/database without the user needing to run a local mysql server.

The database contains only 2 tables.

Comment: Create another database in the same server and create a job that runs regularly to sync the tables by SSIS...

Comment: If you want to have a offline feature, i think the users must have mysql installed on their client. Or you make use of a ms access database, xml file or something that is dumped from the server while online that could be read as datasource when offline.

Answer (score 1):

well since you want it offline without installing a database (which would be the easyest) i'd suggest storing it in an .xml file.
I take it you already have a piece of code to retrieve data from a database, so simply use that code and store all the data in a `DataTable` or custom Class, then with this peace of code save and load it

```
public static void Save(string FileName, object o)
{
    using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FileName))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(writer, o);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}

public static object Load(string FileName, Type t)
{
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(FileName))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(t);
        return serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

assuming you want to sync the database and not completely select the entire database every time you could add a column to your tables such as DateTimeModified and select everything that has been modified/added after the last sync.

Comment: Will crash when the database grows up.